# Getting contents of ContentPlaceHolder within C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, contentplaceholder

I've got a Master Page with multiple ContentPlaceHolders.  One of them will sometimes be empty.  If they both have content, I'd like to make visible a buffer  so there is some space between them, but this  should remain hidden otherwise.

My question is, how can I determine from the C# code-behind of my Master Page whether the ContentPlaceHolder of a child page has any content assigned to it?  All I really want is a boolean yes/no answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
YourContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Count > 0
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: I don't think this will work if plain HTML is placed there. As far as I know only the server side controls are in the .Controls property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but it seems you just need to get spacing. Why not just wrap the first ContentPlaceHolder in a `div` with a `padding-bottom`? There may be a more efficient way to do this, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically add a div to your first ContentPlaceHolder with something like ...

```
<div class="spacer" />
```

and in your css have this ...

```
div.spacer { margin-bottom: 5ex; }
```

you may need to put a `&nbsp` in the div to get around some browser bugs :)